# How to customize color of specific point in Google charts

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-visualization

How  to customize color of specific date point on data chart from [Google analytics embedded API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/embed/v1/) . 
After I read [Google Visualization API documentation](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference) I tried this code but it didn't work:

```
var sessionsOverMonth = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart({
        reportType: 'ga',
        query: {
            'dimensions': 'ga:date',
            'metrics': 'ga:sessions',
            'start-date': '30daysAgo',
            'end-date': 'yesterday',
        },
        chart: {
            type: 'LINE',
            container: 'sessions-over-month',
            options: {width: '100%' ,
                series: {
                    0: { pointShape: { type: 'star', sides: 5, dent: 0.05 }},
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

how to catch specific date on chart and customize it ?

Answer (score 0):

settings within the `series` option, will affect the entire data series, or column of data

to change a specific point within a series, requires using a [column role](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/roles#what-roles-are-available),
specifically --> *style*

the following working snippet shows how in the `google-visualization` library

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['corechart']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Date', 'y', {role: 'style'}],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 1), 0, null],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 2), 1, null],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 3), 2, 'point {size: 16; shape-type: star; fill-color: #d81b60;}'],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 4), 3, null],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 5), 4, null],
    [new Date(2017, 2, 6), 5, null]
  ]);

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
  chart.draw(data, {
    pointSize: 6
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="chart_div"></div>
```

Comment: i'm not sure about `google-analytics`, is there a column in the data set you can use as a _style_ column?

Comment: Yes WhiteHat,your code is working on visualization,but in status google analytics,there isn't style attribute for chart except width attribute.